# How can I have a shared object between sockets in gevent's Socket io module

Tags: python, socket.io, gevent

I am trying to implement sockets using the client library of `socket.io` and the server implementation for Python, [gevent-socketio](http://gevent-socketio.readthedocs.org/). I got the server to run and the sockets to work. However, I am trying to implement some simple in-browser game (that I didn't write!) and the game happens completely within one instance of the game class. It works something like this:

```
game = Game([player1,player2])
game.turn(player1, action_one)
game.turn(player2, action_two)
...
print game.winner()
```

Since I want to use sockets for the turns, I need some way to share the `game` object on the server side between the different sockets (players). How could I do this? I really would not like to store each state of the game on the disk or in some database. Is there any other option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like [Pyro](http://packages.python.org/Pyro4/intro.html) is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

It's not cleare what's your plroblem in.
If you processs different socket's io in the same process (probably, in different greenletes), it's not a problem to share any data between different socket handlers. Could you describe your problem with more details?